# Cat's nose leaking drops when petted

Tags: cats, ears-nose-throat

When I pet my cat, she purrs and leaks tiny drops of clear liquid from the base of her nose. When she's really enjoying herself she can leak a drop or two every minute.

My first guess is that it may be pheromones, but it seems to leak from the vomeronasal organ...

Does anyone know what this dicharge is? Is it normal, or is it an indication that my cat should see a Veteranarian?

Answer (score 7):

It does sound normal to me.

Many cats start to produce more saliva when being petted. The reason for this is not fully known, but it might be a response that has its origin in the brain of your cat, in the cat's pleasure center. It is the same response type as when the cat sees food and starts eating.

[Why Does my Cat Drool when Petted?](https://www.animalwised.com/why-does-my-cat-drool-when-petted-2460.html)

If a cat feels uncomfortable it will produce more saliva and lick its nose often, so this is a sign that a cat is unsure of the situation.

If a cat does have some problem in its mouth it will produce excess saliva. So if this happens you need to take it to the vet.

Answer (score 4):

As Trond mentioned, this is completely normal.

Some cats produce saliva when really enjoying themselves, causing drooling. Others will release more liquid from their nasal cavities and eyes that their nose will drip. I've had one cat who drooled, and I now have one whose nose drips.

As long as this doesn't cause any problems for the cat, such as sneezing or problems breathing, and the liquid is clear and without smell I wouldn't worry about it.